# ORDER BY generating error in Google Sheets' QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, sorting

I'm getting a '#Value!' error when I try to sort data returned by a `QUERY` statement.  This is the basic statement:
`=query('Raw Data'!A:G,"Select A, C, D, sum(G) where B='instagram' and (D='Female Followers Age' or D='Male Followers Age') and A <> '#N/A' group by D, C, A label A 'Handle', C 'Country', D 'Segment', sum(G) 'Share'",0)`

Adding an `ORDER BY` statement to the end of it to sort on column A generates a #Value! error.  I saw some responses on forums suggesting column numbers should be used in place of letters with the order by clause.  However, I have tried replacing `order by A` with `order by 1`, but it generates the same error.

`=query('Raw Data'!A:G,"Select A, C, D, sum(G) where B='instagram' and (D='Female Followers Age' or D='Male Followers Age') and A <> '#N/A' group by D, C, A label A 'Handle', C 'Country', D 'Segment', sum(G) 'Share' order by A",0)`

Answer (score 2):

In a query statement, the clauses must be given in the order specified in the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax). The `order by` clause must come after `group by` and before `label`, like this:

```
=query( 
  'Raw Data'!A:G, 
  "select A, C, D, sum(G) 
   where B = 'instagram' 
   and (D = 'Female Followers Age' or D = 'Male Followers Age') 
   and A <> '#N/A' 
   group by D, C, A 
   order by A 
   label A 'Handle', C 'Country', D 'Segment', sum(G) 'Share' ", 
  0 
)
```